# Convolutional neural network Newbie

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN so I am trying to learn to code it with python by following tutorials online, and I came up to this tutorial: https://medium.com/nybles/create-your-first-image-recognition-classifier-using-cnn-keras-and-tensorflow-backend-6eaab98d14dd
I followed the code and all but I get this small error that I can't seem to know the solution:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'random.jpg'

This is the code where the error points out to:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('random.jpg',target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] >= 0.5:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
    print(prediction)
```

I'm going to include the whole code just in case people want to see: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ew22sJOvl5Ea9VTM_PXqVKNZJm1OuXTG

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you have the image file `random.jpg`? If yes, is it in the same location as the file you are running?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give full path to the image or put code file and the image to the same file.

Comment: Do I just put the directory of the image inside the same apostrophe as the random .jpg?

Comment: Yes, if the image and code is on the some directory code can find random.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read on the blog post, he used just a random dog image (downloaded from any web), name it as "random.jpg", and use it as a test image. You can just seek for any dog/cat image around the web, download and rename it as "random.jpg".

The point is, you know the image is a dog or cat, then test your model to predict what image it is.

Comment: Ow I see now, I just want to know how will I be able to do that? Do I just put the directory on the same apostrophe symbol of the random.jpg?

Comment: Putting the 'random.jpg' file on the same directory as your python code would be the easiest

Answer (score 0):

You need to put 'random.jpg' into your working directory. That is put any file( a dog, cat, or any) with that name inside your folder :)